# Weird graphical issue with UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I tried to put a `UIPickerView` in a `UIViewController` and show a simple items in it with this code:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    pickerLabel.text = "10"
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    pickerLabel.sizeToFit()
    return pickerLabel
}
```

everything is fine but when I changed `numberOfComponents` to 2 picker view didn't show correct. Why this is happening?(Xcode 8 iOS 10)
[image: with 2 component]
[image: with 3 component]

Comment: Giving a fixed width in the picker view delegate method "func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat { return 80}", does solve it but this is a hack and will break when the number of components increases or decreases

Comment: so this is a bug in SDK or something else? @NaveenRamanathan

Comment: I can't be 100% sure,  but the same thing happens with the default date picker in iOS Settings->General->Date time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to notice here:

1. You have used: `pickerLabel.sizeToFit()` which would size the label to its content.
2. Next is that if you comment `pickerLabel.sizeToFit()` and put a background color to your label. You'd get the following result

[image]

As you can see in here that PickerView has a curvature and a distance in between cells which is causing this issue. So solution is you can give a width to your label & no size to fit and apply a background while testing your result and come to the best possible combination.

For instance, check the iOS Native clock timer:

[image]

"They have tried playing around with width of label and index"

**Please note:**

The curvature is causing the width to decrease and label is center aligned so it is taking it along the path of decreasing width, if you get what i'm trying to say here.

This should explain it.

Cheers!

Comment: But when I'm using `titleForRow` with the default view the same thing happens. Thats not because of my `UILabel`!

Comment: @Amir_P: My Friend, i never meant that the `UILabel` that you've created has caused the issue, its the `UIPickerView` control's design itself, so basically you need to hack the UI and show different widths based on the selected one and ones that are not. Also take into account, the distance in-between

Comment: One more question : why that doesn't happen with 1,3,4,... components? only with 2

Comment: With 1 component: center remains the same, regardless of curvature. Because the cell loading is also at the center of the screen, so center of label for a cell centered in the view is the same point.

For components more than 2: `The deviation in curvature is very low`, please notice in image attached. Thanks!

http://i63.tinypic.com/24yckyr.png